# Upload a file in soapUI

Tags: java, http, attachment, soapui

I'm uploading a file to our upload service using soapUI. The file will upload correctly when using GUI invocation of the tool. However we're invoking the command line version from our framework.

It appears that soapUI command line invocation is unable to construct the Content-Disposition in the http request correctly and when it attempts to add the "filename" parameter an exception is thrown since this is unexpected. Here's the stack trace:

```
14:33:51,358 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occured [Expected ';', got "filename"], see error log for details
javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Expected ';', got "filename"
    at javax.mail.internet.ParameterList.<init>(ParameterList.java:280)
    at javax.mail.internet.ContentDisposition.<init>(ContentDisposition.java:96)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1338)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1008)
    at javax.mail.internet.PreencodedMimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(PreencodedMimeBodyPart.java:117)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:414)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1285)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2071)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2039)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.HttpRequestFilter.filterHttpRequest(HttpRequestFilter.java:240)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filterAbstractHttpRequest(AbstractRequestFilter.java:41)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filterRequest(AbstractRequestFilter.java:31)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:130)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:122)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.submitRequest(WsdlSubmit.java:75)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.http.HttpRequest.submit(HttpRequest.java:258)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.HttpTestRequestStep.run(HttpTestRequestStep.java:253)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:193)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.internalRun(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:124)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.internalRun(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:39)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:137)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.start(AbstractTestRunner.java:80)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.run(WsdlTestCase.java:578)
    at awris.product.testengine.commands.service.SoapUICommand$BetterSoapUITestCaseRunner.runTestCase(SoapUICommand.java:303)
    at com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner.runRunner(SoapUITestCaseRunner.java:318)
    at com.eviware.soapui.tools.AbstractSoapUIRunner.run(AbstractSoapUIRunner.java:133)
    at awris.product.testengine.commands.service.SoapUICommand.execute(SoapUICommand.java:76)
    at awris.product.testengine.TestRunner.executeCommands(TestRunner.java:123)
    at awris.product.testengine.TestRunner.doTest(TestRunner.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.invokeMethod(MethodHelper.java:609)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodHelper.java:727)
......
```

When the test runs the file fails to upload because the attachment is not present from the header construction blowing out. Why is this happening from the command line invocation and not in the GUI and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found the solution myself. The version of the soapUI GUI I was using was 3.6.1 and the version of the command line invocation was 3.0.1 which had a bug in it which prevents constructs the Content-Disposition incorrectly for file upload requests. i.e. it does not include the filename parameter in the Content-Disposition.

Updating the version to 3.6.1 corrected the issue for me.